# Find the order of zeros

Tags: complex-analysis

The given function is $f(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z}$, so to find the order of zeros first we have to find the zeros, in this case $f(z)=0$ iff $z=(2n+1)\pi, n\in\Bbb Z$. Those are a lot of zeros and I'm not sure what to do next, I figure maybe pick one, say $z=\pi$, so 
$$f'(z)=\frac{z\cos(z)-\sin(z)}{z^2}=\frac{\pi\cos\pi-\sin\pi}{\pi^2}\not=0$$
That way we get that $\pi$ is a zero of order $1$, that means all of the othet zeros are too of order $1$? how do I find the order of zeros?

Comment: No, the zeros are $n \pi$ for $n \in {\mathbb Z} \backslash \{0\}$.

Comment: Why do you take "only" the odd multiples of $\;\pi\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio because I copied it wrong from my notebook

Comment: You could show that the derivative is not zero at each of the zeros. Thus verifying that they are all order one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(z) = g(z)/h(z)$ where $g$ and $h$ are analytic and $g$ has a zero of order $k$ at $z=p$ while $h(z) \ne 0$, then $f$ has a zero of order $k$ there as well.